# Building RAD7 project from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, ant, build-process

We have existing projects set with compilation dependencies in a RAD7 IDE.
Is it possible to create automated build script from the existing project structure?
We have IBM portal projects and regular WEB and enterprise projects.

Maven and Ant are possible solutions but can we use these tools to build existing projects
from command line without using the IDE itself?

Also is it possible to call RAD \ eclipse core compilation from command line or API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into "headless mode". That's basically running the IDE to perform its work without the IDE showing up.

I don't have any direct experience but one of the teams in our lab used RAD in headless mode to automate builds for an Eclipse/System-z interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on headless Ant builds in chapter 23 of the [Rational Application Developer V7 Programming Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247501.html) Rebook. There's more documentation in the [IBM Rational Application Developer Version 7.0.0.x Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp) (which you should also be able to find in the help).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of projects already using Tycho to build Eclipse components using Maven:

There is a somewhat dated tutorial for Tycho here: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/11/building-eclipse-plugins-with-maven-tycho/

For more information about the Tycho development effort: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/03/the-future-of-maven-osgi-join-the-tycho-users-mailing-list/

Answer (score 0):

Based off the answer in [Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line). You can do the following

```
"%RAD_INSTALL%\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe" -Dwtp.autotest.noninteractive=true -cp "%RAD_INSTALL%\startup.jar" org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main  -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild  -data "%WORKSPACE%"
```

Where you configure the variables `%RAD_INSTALL%` to your instance of RAD and `%WORKSPACE%` to the workspace which houses the projects you want to biuld.