# Is it possible to run the Eclipse JDT compiler from the command line, like javac?

Tags: command-line, javac, eclipse-jdt

I'd like to do some command-line Java compiling of individual Java source files on a machine that has Eclipse installed. However, I don't have permissions to install a full Java SDK on this machine.

I understand that Eclipse compiles through its [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/), not using `javac`.

Is is possible to use the Eclipse compiler from the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few more minutes of searching and I found this in the [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm), under the section "Running the Batch Compiler":

```
java -jar org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.4.0<qualifier>.jar -classpath rt.jar A.java
```

or:

```
java -jar ecj.jar -classpath rt.jar A.java
```

I also found this Q/A on [how to build an entire Eclipse project from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line), which contains some of the same information, but since it didn't show up in my initial search I'm leaving this question open.

<sub>(And about 2 sec before I was going to click "Post Your Answer", Jon Skeet's reply popped up.)</sub>

---

The exact syntax that worked for me (Sun JRE is in the Windows PATH, Eclipse version is Galileo build 20100218-1602):

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.5.2.v_981_R35x.jar" test.java
```

I omitted the `-classpath rt.jar` and it still worked. Couldn't find the 'ecj.jar' file in this build.

It seems that the specific instructions for this do change from release to release, so *caveat coder*.