# android unit tests via command line

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing, adb

I have an Android Project and a TestProject, and I've written some unit tests. I can run all Tests in eclipse.

No I try to run the tests via command-line, because I want to parse the output:
adb shell am instrument -w -r  com.allg.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Everything seems fine. But when I am editing a TestCase, and run the command again, the output will not change (although I changed a test). I have to run the tests in eclipse first, to refresh the command line test result.

How is this possible?

Comment: Did you rebuild and re-install your testproject before running the tests again?

Comment: no, how can I do this via command line?

Comment: something like this in case you use ant: ant buid, adb install

Comment: I am not using ant, I created the project with eclipse, so I have no build.xml ... Could I integrate a build.xml? How must it look like?

Comment: This question has some answers where eclipse projects are built via command-line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

That command line only runs the tests that are on the device. If you've edited a TestCase, you'll need to recompile it, and reinstall it on to the device.