# How to export a .jar file from VsCode?

Tags: executable-jar, vscode-tasks

I've researched a lot about how to export a .jar file from VsCode, but unsuccessfully.

Somebody save me please!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the terminal.

[How to do Eclipse's "export jar" from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828493/how-to-do-eclipses-export-jar-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Is it possible out of terminal?