# excluding eclipse's excludes in an ant script

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

In eclipse users have the ability to *exclude* files from the build. Eclipse will then modify the `.classpath` and create the following entry so that eclipse knows not to build the particular files when compiling.

`<classpathentry excluding="file1|file2|file3" kind="src" path="src"/>`

I am creating ant scripts for several android projects. I am using the ADT auto generated script and overriding the `-compile` task. **I was wondering if there was a way that i can get a list of the files that are being excluded?**

I was thinking of having a task in ant that would parse the `.classpath` file and retrieve the file names and then use them that way... but i was hoping there was an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: Parsing the .classpath might be an option, but it might be done already: http://joeygibson.com/2004/06/15/free-eclipse-classpath-ant-task/

Comment: I am really wanting a way to not have to add plugins to ant or anything else. This way the developers only have to have ant, the source and the build files.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option could be to build project from command line, using Eclipse's [command line builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line). you can incorporate it into an ant script too.

Comment: Thank you, will look into that as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about using **Export->General->ANT files**?
This creates a ant build script respecting the excluded classes.

Comment: This is using the android autogenerated build script.