# How to build mixed Scala\Java Eclipse workspace automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, continuous-integration, build-script

I have an Eclipse (3.7.2 + Scala 2.10 plugin) workspace. It contains more than 10 Scala and Java projects. I want to organize simple CI build. Just full recompilation (without testing, distribution, style checking ...)  Is fast and simple-reproducible path for build script generation exists? I try to export Ant script with standard Eclipse wizard, but result is machine-dependent and does not contains compilation for Scala projects. In sbt + eclipse plugin I have a problem with Java project compilation. More then that, in this case we should support dependences manually. It is not good idea for huge and fast  growing workspace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to generate a build script from Eclipse which meets your requirements. If you're looking for something reproducible, your best bet is to use an external build tool and generate your Eclipse artifacts based on its model. I've found [M2E](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) to be the best round trip solution support both Java and Scala builds as well as mixed builds. To use this approach, you would need to use Maven as the external build technology. As an alternative option, you could generate Eclipse artifacts using some external build tool. For instance, you can use [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) and [SBTEclipsify](https://github.com/musk/SbtEclipsify), Ant and [Ant-Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-eclipse/) or Maven to generate Eclipse projects. With this approach, you would have to regenerate the projects every time the build changes. Other build tools probably provide similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Seems, that this technology is very stable. 1 hour is not enough for configure CI. I found, that it is possible to run [eclipsec from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line), but for Scala+Java workspace I get an error in scala tool initialisation.