# building library in eclipse via command line for libjingle

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-construction, webrtc, libjingle

I have finished downloading and importing android demo project to eclipse  but unable to build :

```
From the IDE, just open the project file and compile. From command line, see below:
=== Windows =

devenv -build "Debug" libjingle.sln
devenv -build "Release" libjingle.sln
```

from link :

```
https://code.google.com/p/libjingle/source/browse/wiki/GettingStarted.wiki?r=258
```

I have tried this [Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line?rq=1) but its still is not compiling .As I still see these errors in eclipse :

```
I420Frame cannot be resolved to a type  

IceCandidate cannot be resolved to a type   

MediaConstraints cannot be resolved to a type

PeerConnection cannot be resolved to a type 


MediaStream cannot be resolved to a type    

iceServers cannot be resolved or is not a field

StatsReport cannot be resolved to a type    

SessionDescription cannot be resolved   

SdpObserver cannot be resolved to a type

The import org.webrtc cannot be resolved    AppRTCClient.java   /AppRTCDemoActivity/src/org/appspot/apprtc
```

Please help me out .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this issue ??