# What's the fastest way to get all build errors in a Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ant

Currently I'm looking at integrating some build processes into my source control (Git hooks specifically). I'm trying to write a pre-commit hook that checks for build errors in my Java project (a medium-large test development project) and fails to allow commits that contain errors in the build. This is turning out to be rather challenging.

The approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line) uses a command-line Eclipse tool to build and output warnings and errors. This does technically work, but it's slow and may cause problems with the Eclipse IDE (I've already had heap allocation errors). I've also looked at solutions using [ant](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/) but these approaches don't seem to be a simple one-line solution, and may still be slow.

My main question: what's the *fastest* (run-time compilation speed) way to build and validate a Java project, by command line? I'd like a solution that returns 0 with no errors and something else if errors are present, but I'm willing to look at other things.

Comment: Wow. That really is from the "if it compiles, ship it" school. What about blocking a commit if unit tests fail too?

Comment: @Bathsheba You gotta learn to walk before you run ;)

Comment: indeed you do. Have an upvote.

Comment: You know you can look at errors in the problems tab of eclipse after you (clean &) build the project, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with some basics:

- pre-commit hooks run on the server and not the client. There is no working directory by default. You have to make sure that `javac` is available, and is the correct version.
- Your pre-commit hook will *freeze up* the user's terminal until completion.

Now, how long will it take to checkout a fresh copy of your Java project, run Ant, wait for it to compile, and then process the output of the compile? a minute or two? 20 seconds? 10 seconds? Even 10 seconds will feel like forever as you wait for the Git push to complete. And, if other users want to commit code, they have to also wait.

A better, and easier approach is to use a *Continuous Build Server* like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Jenkins is easy to setup. (It comes with its own application server built in) and has hundreds of *plugins* that you can use to help report the health of your project. If a compile cannot happen, Jenkins will email the culprit and whomever else you mention.

We have our Jenkins setup to do Ant builds, Maven builds, and use either Git or Subversion as our repository (depending upon the project). Jenkins builds the project, keeps the console log, and will *fail* the build if `build.xml` fails. At our place, this means I start pestering the developer to fix the problem or to undo their changes. At my last workplace, developers were given 10 minutes to fix the build, or I would undo their changes.

Not only can Jenkins let you know when a build fails, but has plugins that can report on the Java compiler warnings, Javadoc warnings, run [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net), find duplicate lines of code (via CPD that comes with PMD), and then report everything in a series of graphs. You can also mark builds as *unstable* (build completes, but is problematic) or simply fail the build based upon the number of issues found with these tools.

Jenkins can also run Unit tests, and again graph the results, then run coverage analysis with [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) or [Cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) or [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net).

So, take a look at Jenkins. It's easy to setup and will do exactly what you want and more.

Comment: We currently do a Jenkins server to take care of running tests and build jobs. I'll see what else it can do for us.

Comment: Take a look at the [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) for Jenkins. This will count all warnings and errors when you do a build. It will also count JavaDoc warnings. Plus, if you have another type of build process, you can use regular expressions to filter out those warnings too. We use this for our auto-configuration testing.

Answer (score 1):

Ant. There isn't going to be a "one-line-solution". Write an ANT script that compiles the code, and fails if there are any errors. It's not easy, but it's the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the choices you mention, Ant is the best.  But let's face it, writing XML sucks.  My guess is that any build tool will fail and return an error code when compilation fails.  My favorite is [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/), but there's a bit of a learning curve if you aren't into Scala (and even those in Scala like to complain about sbt).  Another great option IMO is [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).  You write your scripts in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) which is a dynamically-typed superset of Java.

Answer (score -2):

Jenkins may be a something you could look at

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'd suggest that you take a look at this [checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104422/is-it-ok-for-stack-overflow-to-treat-all-questions-answers-equally?rq=1) and see if you can provide some more insights/details into the answer you are providing.