# Eclipse + Selenium + TestNG - Continuous Integration - **No** Ant, Maven, Etc

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, continuous-integration, testng

I'm looking at setting up a continuous integration server for running selenium and testng unit tests.

I know you can do so by using maven or ant, but I don't want to add a 2nd build system into our project. I've read all about it, another team here is using maven, but I'm trying as hard as I can to avoid it. (Would appreciate not turning this into an Ant or Maven debate.)

From what I've read, if I was using Intellij their TeamCity product could do this no problem from the project config files - but we're not (unfortunately, I'd love to), we're using Eclipse. If we were using Netbeans, apparently everything is already stored as an Ant project so that wouldn't be a problem.

Curious if anyone has had any success setting up a continuous integration server with an  Eclipse project, **without** adding in another build tool to the project. We can do this without a problem on a developers local machine, seems like it shouldn't be to hard to do for an integration server...

**Edit**: I found another stack overflow topic on how to run the eclipse build from the command line -
[Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line)

"eclipsec.exe -noSplash -data "D:\Source\MyProject\workspace" -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild"

I tried it out, and manually copying over the results into Tomcat definitely works (though you end up copying .class files rather than a .jar file). Most of the continuous integration products say they can use any command line tool to do the build.

Still wondering if anyone has done it before though...

Comment: Jenkins is built to support Maven and Ant.  Why do you think it comes vanilla with it? why would you go away from it?

Comment: As I said in my post, I don't want to open up a topic that ends up in a flame war, but it's simply that all the info needed for building the project is already in the eclipse project files. There's no reason to copy this info into yet another tool, then have to deal with trying to keep 2 sets of build info in sync. It would be much easier to just use the eclipse project files so that it's all in one place.

Comment: Just thought I would comment to follow up, in case anyone else runs across this. Unfortunately, as no one else had an answer, I didn't have a lot of time to look into this.

It turns out that Eclipse can export it's project settings to an ant file. (File-Export->General->Ant Build Files). So I exported the build file to ant. Then however, I needed a .war file, so I added this to the file to build the .war file -

Comment: <target name="war" description="Bundles the application as a WAR file" depends="clean, build">
     <mkdir dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
      
     <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes">
             <fileset dir="build/classes">
              <include name="**/*.*"/>
             </fileset>
     </copy>
      
     <war destfile="SeleniumTestingMsa.war"
         basedir="WebContent"
         needxmlfile="false">
     </war>
 </target>

Comment: If I come back to it and find a better solution, I will post back, but that got things running for now without needing to hand edit a *lot* of stuff.