# eclipsec.exe options/ command line usage?

Tags: eclipse, command-line

Is there an exhaustive list of documented commands that I can use with `eclipsec.exe`?

[Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line)

I see that we can build projects outside GUI. Is the command line powerful enough to control any other features inside eclipse GUI?

For example : Is it possible to launch a saved "Java Application" inside eclipse workspace from the command line directly?

Basically, I want to explore all options that I have on eclipsec.exe. I tried `eclipsec.exe --help` and `eclipsec.exe -help` to see if I can get some help but none of them work.

Comment: I doubt that there is a single list as the options depend on the `-application` parameter and there are a lot of applications (and you can also write your own).

Comment: IBM FTW! Welcome to the club.
@greg-449 And yet here we are on StackOverflow looking for the -h switch. There's no excuse for not having a message with at least what you've written here. My understanding is that there is always available a minimum of one option: -application. Should the user search on google or reverse-engineer your application to find out?
The compiler should crash when you try to compile a program lacking a help/usage switch. End of story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eclipse runtime options
- http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html
using p2 director to install/uninstall plugins
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Director_application
- http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html

There is also linked Question [Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line)

Comment: The question was about eclipsec.exe, not eclipse.exe, wasn't it?

Comment: On windows handling command line is via `eclipsec.exe` executable, while on Linux it is the same `eclipse` file