# How to add a jar file to an eclipse java project from command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, cmd, classpath

I want to compile an eclipse java project from command line. To make it easier I've put all my java files and the jar file that I need in my program in one direcotry. The path to the said direcory is:

```
 C:\Users\Besi\Desktop\Test\src
```

My main class is called Program.java

Now, I am having problems with importing the jar file and compiling my main class. I mean I cannot compile it without importing the jar file but at the same time I don't know how to this in the command line. I tried this:

```
 javac -classpath ".:C:\Users\Besi\Desktop\Test\src\javatuples-1.2;" Program.java
```

but it doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: What is the structure inside the Test\src folder? Is javatuples-1.2 a jar?

Comment: yes,  javatuples-1.2 is a jar. Inside Test\src folder I have all my java files (including Program.java) that I want to compile and javatuples-1.2 jar

Comment: Try `".:C:\Users\Besi\Desktop\Test\src\*"` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: or just add the .jar extension to `javatuples-1.2.jar`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried both and I still get errors related to the lack of javatuples jar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your end goal (and not simply trying to "add a jar file to an Eclipse java project from the command line" as your actual question title states):

> I want to compile an eclipse java project from command line.

Turns out that you can compile your Eclipse project from the command line without having to place your .jar files and .java files in the same directory.

I just did it (and ensured I had two .jar files in my Eclipse project) using the following command as executed from the workspace directory (which I modified using the information from your question, assuming `C:\Users\Besi\Desktop\Test` is the workspace of your project, and assuming you're running Windows):

```
eclipsec.exe -noSplash -data "C:\Users\Besi\Desktop\Test" -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild
```

<sub>Because I cannot yet comment, I am posting this as an answer, even though I adapted this answer based on the contents of a [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line). Please edit accordingly if this causes any trouble, thanks.</sub>

Comment: Thank you but I will have to compile this project from an svn repository and very likely on a computer that does not have eclipse installed so I cannot use this method

Comment: Understood, I will update if I find a more generic solution. Please include that information in the question next time :).

Comment: @BesSa can you update the question to ask for a generic solution that does not use Eclipse so future answers can be useful to you?