# Execute eclipse app from command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I hava a big java application in Eclipse and now I want run from command line, so I am in path: bin and run java Main but the problem:

Error: Could not find or load main class Main

What can I do?

Comment: What is "big"?  Have you looked at executable jars yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Eclipse Java Project from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line)