# How to build Eclipse Android Library Project in Command Line (Terminal)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, command-line, build

I am trying to use .so and .jar files from an eclipse based android project on my Android Studio project. I can build the .so and copy it to the jniLibs folder.

However, I am not clear about how to build the .jar file from the eclipse project without opening it.

Is there a way to build the .jar for a eclipse based android project in command line?

Comment: In Android/Eclipse time, `ant` was used for command line builds. Try [ant+android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant+android) tags

Comment: [Non-ant way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/206473/), I have never tried this though.