# Locating the corresponding .classpath file for a .java source file

Tags: java, file, classpath, filetree

Let's say I have a java file `C:\workspace\project\src\packagename\foobar.java`. Now, I would like to compile this file at runtime, but for that I need the corresponding `.classpath` file (or rather, it's entries), located at `C:\workspace\project\.classpath`, so that I can pass the dependencies with the `-classpath` argument (this approach works if I hard-code it, but that's obviously only proof-of-concept, not the goal).

How would I go about finding the `.classpath` file?

My idea was walking the file tree bottom up, starting at `foobar.java`, until I get to a level where a `.classpath` file exists which I can then use.

However, I'm a) not sure that this is the way to do it, and b) not sure *how* to walk the file tree bottom up, other than `String.split`-ting the file and removing the segments, starting at the end. That is super ugly, though, and I refuse to believe that there is no better option.

Comment: I believe you mean to comment on your answer, though ^^

Comment: @GhostCat You shall be absolved of your sins :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking how to write Java code that *understands* the layout and structure of say *eclipse* project directories. To then "mimic" eclipse and compile files for you.

This is probably a really bad idea. You see, unless you are talking about very small and "reduced" projects only, sooner or later, you will encounter projects that are large, and each one a bit different than the other. You will be constantly trying to get things right, and each time you fixed a bug, another project comes along and something new shows up and your solution breaks. Because you can't get a robust "copy" of the eclipse build code unless you use that build code.

Thus my suggestion:

- figure if there is a way to drive eclipse (or whatever IDE project files you are talking about) via command line. Use the build code that does know how to build these things. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line) how to do that for eclipse.
- see if it is possible to change such projects to have a maven/gradle build configuration. because then you can *easily* build that thing using maven/gradle

Comment: What about *ant*? What I meant, if I don't want to use maven or gradle...

Comment: @zlakad Well, it is 2018, isn't it? *ant* is for sure an option, but one that feels more like 2005. Meaning: when you start thinking about build systems today, then picking *ant* would probably be an indication that something about the solution is fishy.

Comment: Yep, but I have some hard feeling that all of these tools will be obsolete when we switch to JDK 9 +

Comment: the projects *do* have gradle build files. What I want to do is take a number of tests, apply a series of regexes that perform some basic replace operations, and then execute the changed tests again to see if any errors occured. If so, I open the failed tests in Eclipse. Anyhow, I don't really know anything about building a project with gradle at runtime, either. Do you know a good place to start?

Comment: Start by opening a command shell and running gradle manually. Then take the corresponding commands have them run with java.

Comment: @zlakad And why should that be? Yes, java9 introduces a module system. And of course people building tools have to adapt their tools, and people **building** projects with tools have to adapt their project settings (and possibly source code) to stay in business with java9. Sometimes people put a **ton** of effort into their build setup - do you really think they will throw all of that away because the JDK comes with *some* tooling that is a bit better here or there? Sure, jlink helps putting together modules. But these modules must still be **built** before you can use jlink to link them.

Comment: Well ... I guess I could have come up with that myself. Dumb me ^^

Comment: @GhostCat Well, it was just my opinion - I am letting the possibility it could be wrong. Battles will go on ;)

Comment: @PixelMaster, welcome to the club (dumb me, also). :)

Comment: @PixelMaster Well, seriously: think simple. Try to "invent" yourself as few things as possible. Gradle is a command-line focused tool, and it is *designed* to be running within a JVM (formerly using groovy, now with Kotlin). Besides that, let me know what else I could add to get into upvote/accept areas ;-)