# How to add projects to eclipse via command line?

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to build java projects using eclipse command line tool. I have been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line). However, it doesn't talk about how to add projects to the newly created workspace via command line.

P.S. I am working on headless Linux box and hence I can't launch eclipse UI and add projects to the workspace from there.

Comment: what about copying them to your workspace ?

Comment: You can use gradle build tool to generate eclipse projects. But really, take one advice: do _not_ use eclipse for headless building, use gradle or maven, but do not use eclipse. Having migrated a project of about 300 OSGi modules from a headless PDE build to a gradle build I really know what I am talking about, be good to yourself and everybody on the project and drop the idea all together.

Comment: @OlegSklyar I think your comment should become the accepted answer!

Comment: @HonzaZidek I wish everybody would see it that way. But for all those who want to build an Eclipse RCP application with gradle here is the plugin I wrote for that 300-large OSGi/RCP project https://github.com/teris-io/nox Undocumented, but I will be happy to write basic docs if there is interest

Comment: @OlegSklyar I completely agree. However, this is a legacy project and can't be migrated to maven or gradle as of now.

Comment: Add gradle and generate project files of your liking in just a few lines of code.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the direction.

Comment: You could write an Eclipse Application that leverages the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.datatransfer.SmartImportJob` (and perhaps make it usable in a headless environment) and contribute it as a patch to the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` owner plug-in.