# Replicating an eclipse build in Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, compiler-errors, devops

Currently I am working on a project where I am configuring a deployment job for a very big and old Java project. The problem is the build compiling stage. Currently, we are building the project through eclipse, however, we are trying to switch to Maven to make it easier to deploy through Jenkins. The problem with switching to Maven is that we would have to restructure the entire project in order to fit the Maven archetype. I was wondering if there was a way in Jenkins via a Jenkins plugin or build framework in which I could build the Java project in the same exact way it is currently built in Eclipse without changing anything with its structure.

Comment: You can probably see what command are executed by Eclipse during local build. Then you can invoke those command as build steps in Jenkins.

Comment: Using Eclipse itself to build on the command line is possible according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line