# How to clean/publish a tomcat server in Eclipse headless mode or emulate its behavior?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, liferay

I need to build a liferay portlet/project and then run the server from CLI, I use a headless eclipse run as detailed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206473/build-eclipse-java-project-from-command-line) to clean and build my projects, but these files aren't being copied to the server's webapps's directory, they only change in the workspace, meaning my changes won't show when I run the server.

The project is fairly complicated for me, and has lots of varied files that aren't exclusively class files, so I'm not sure simply copying the .class files will do all the time, especially if there's some cached/outdated files that need removal.

In Eclipse's GUI, in the "servers" tab, clean/publish does the trick with ease, is there a way to emulate that via some assortment of commands, or via running headless Eclipse with some special parameters?

Comment: As you tag Liferay, but don't mention it in the question: Are you recompiling Liferay? Or are you doing anything out of the ordinary that requires you to rebuild everything from scratch?

Comment: the project I'm compiling is a liferay portlet, I forgot to detail that, I will edit now, I don't know if it being liferay or not affects that, I'm not very familiar with these frameworks.

Comment: Never mind, liferay is mentioned as the type of the project, but do I need to add more details? I don't know much about liferay to be honest.