# How to export Eclipse RCP through command line

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

We have an Eclipse RCP product, for automation purpose, we'd like to export this product through the command line.

Actually, I found someone asked the similar questions before, such as [Building Eclipse plugins and features on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133234/building-eclipse-plugins-and-features-on-the-command-line). I followed the Eclipse PDE help guides, and built the product successfully by command line. But there is no executale file in the builded zip file.

How can I, by command line, get the same exported the RCP product as we get with the help of PDE UI? Thanks!

---

Calvin

Answer (score 4):

[Eclipse Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) is a great way to produce Eclipse RCP products.  I am using it to build both eclipse update-sites and a product.  There are lots of examples online for how to setup your project files, [like this one](https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo) and [this one](https://github.com/caniszczyk/minerva).